# Create Dictionary<String, [SomeStruct]> from [SomeStruct] source-array

Tags: ios, swift

```
var sourceEntries: [Entry] = [entry1, ..., entry14]
var myDict: Dictionary<String, [Entry]> = [:]

for entry in sourceEntries {

    if var array = myDict[entry.attribute1] { theArray.append(entry) }
    else { myDict[entry.attribute1] = [entry] }

}
```

I am intending to create a Dictionary, which matches all the objects of the struct "Eintrag" with the same attribute from the source-Array "alleEinträge" to a String containing the value of the shared attribute. For some reason my final Dictionary just matches Arrays of one element to the Strings, although some Arrays ought to contain up to four elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the array is passed by value (i.e. "copied"), so the array you are writing to when you say `array.append` is not the array that is "inside" the dictionary. You have to write back into the dictionary explicitly if you want to change what's in it.

Try it in a simple situation:

```
    var dict = ["entry":[0,1,2]]
    // your code
    if var array = dict["entry"] { array.append(4) }
    // so what happened?
    println(dict) // [entry: [0, 1, 2]]
```

As you can see, the "4" never got into the dictionary.

You have to write back into the dictionary explicitly:

```
    if var array = dict["entry"] { array.append(4); dict["entry"] = array }
```

---

**FURTHER THOUGHTS:** You got me thinking about whether there might be a more elegant way to do what you're trying to do. I'm not sure whether you will think this is "more elegant", but perhaps it has some appeal.

I will start by setting up a struct (like your Entry) with a `name` attribute:

```
struct Thing : Printable {
    var name : String
    var age : Int
    var description : String {
    return "{\(self.name), \(self.age)}"
    }
}
```

Now I will create an array like your `sourceEntries` array, where some of the structs share the same `name` (like your shared attribute `attribute1`):

```
    let t1 = Thing(name: "Jack", age: 40)
    let t2 = Thing(name: "Jill", age: 38)
    let t3 = Thing(name: "Jill", age: 37)
    let arr = [t1,t2,t3]
```

And of course I will prepare the empty dictionary, like your `myDict`, which I call `d`:

```
    var d = [String : [Thing]]()
```

Now I will create the dictionary! The idea is to use `map` and `filter` together to do all the work of creating key-value pairs, and then we just build the dictionary from those pairs:

```
    let pairs : [(String, [Thing])] = arr.map {
        t in (t.name, arr.filter{$0.name == t.name})
    }
    for pair in pairs { d[pair.0] = pair.1 }
```

Comment: This behavior changed in beta 3. It's much clearer now - arrays are always passed by value - but, as my answer implies, you sometimes have to do a little more work.

Comment: Thank you very much, but as I just recognized, the Array is made of Structures. Don't they behave slightly different at reassigning than classes?

Comment: I don't see what that has to do with it.

Comment: I thought of another way to do it... See my edit to my answer.